# User Customizing Bing Map Infobox Description

Tags: reactjs, bing-maps, inputbox, infobox

I am currently developing an app using bing map v8 web control in react.js. I intend to add an input box in the info box so that users can enter their own description for the infobox. Just wondering is it possible to do it? If yes, can someone give me some hint on how to do it, and if not, is there other ways that I could let the users enter their own title for the pushpin?

I am new to Bing Map api and any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. For some reason textboxs in the infobox can't get focused. I'll have the dev team look into this to see if there is a way around this.

**Update (8/26/2016):** The team has now added support for HTML in descriptions. Textboxes work in infoboxes too. This is currently available in the experimental branch of V8 and will be in the main release branch in a couple of weeks.